# location of werdet, why is it not at the end of a sub-statement?

Tags: subordinate-clause

This is from Luther bible Johannes. (http://www.bibledbdata.org/onlinebibles/german_l/43_004.htm)

4:21 Jesus spricht zu ihr: Weib, glaube mir, es kommt die Zeit, daß ihr weder auf diesem Berge noch zu Jerusalem werdet den Vater anbeten.

I learned that in sub-clause, the main verbe should be placed in the last position, so the normal word order will be `daß ihr weder auf diesem Berge noch zu Jerusalem den Vater anbeten werdet.`  But why is it `daß ihr weder auf diesem Berge noch zu Jerusalem werdet den Vater anbeten.` here? Is it an acceptable form in modern German language? (I'm self learning German and didn't study advanced Grammar yet). Or, is it because the adverb phrase `weder auf diesem Berge noch zu Jerusalem` comes to stress, the order `den Vater anbeten werdet` is inversed to `werdet den Vater anbeten`? Having said it, it seems plausible for me..Please someone explain it to me. Danke!

to `werdet anbeten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question *why* may be hard to give. Luther himself wrote it like this in 1545 ("letzte Hand"):

> Jhesus spricht zu jr / Weib / gleube mir / Es kompt die zeit / das jr weder auff diesem Berge / noch zu Jerusalem werdet den Vater an beten.

You can easily see that 500 years later German developed a bit. Nevertheless it was Martin Luther who with his own wordings tremendously influenced the German language. So your answer may well be: *because Luther said so*.

And indeed even much later "Luther Bible" translations tried to remain as close as possible to Luther with only adapting orthography:

> - Jesus spricht zu ihr: Weib, glaube mir, es kommt die Zeit, daß ihr weder auf diesem Berge noch zu Jerusalem werdet den Vater anbeten.<sup>Luther Bible 1912</sup>

A modern translation will however change the wording according to orthography, grammar rules, and word meanings of today:

> - Jesus spricht zu ihr: Frau, glaube mir, es kommt die Stunde, wo ihr weder auf diesem Berg noch in Jerusalem den Vater anbeten werdet.<sup>[Schlachter Bibel 2000](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlachter-Bibel)</sup>
> - Jesus sagte zu ihr: Glaube mir, Frau, es kommt die Zeit, da werdet ihr den Vater weder auf diesem Berg noch in Jerusalem anbeten.<sup>[Gute Nachricht 1997](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gute_Nachricht_Bibel)</sup>

For a collection of more modern Bible translations see

- [BibleServer](https://www.bibleserver.com/start)

Comment: Oh, I see. Again, That was a clear explanation. :) Thanks!